# Proxy failover solution?

Tags: linux, proxy, squid, failover, open-source

What would be http/ftp proxy failover solutions using open source tools?

I have one squid proxy server on virtual Linux server and need to make a failover server on another one. Proxy must be configurable by end users by manually entering DNS name and port.

Comment: Do you need automatic failover, or are you simply looking for a way to replicate your existing configuration? 'Proxy must be configurable by end users' seems to imply that you only need manual failover?

Comment: I need automatic failover. 'Proxy must be configurable by end users' means, that I can not use autodetection of proxy server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need [Linux-HA](http://www.linux-ha.org/).

> ### Project Goal
>
> Provide a high availability (clustering) solution for Linux which promotes reliability,
>   availability, and serviceability (RAS) through a community development effort.

Answer (score 0):

Here I run 2 squid, linked through heartbeat : if one fail, the other takes hand. Easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

proxy.pac? A user can configure it, and if you serve it right, you can use it for fail-over.

www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/7949.html

Comment: This solution does not fulfill requirement: "Proxy must be configurable by end users by manually entering DNS name and port."

Comment: Sorry - presumed your users would be able to enter the proxy.pac line instead (this is generally in the same place as they would enter a DNS name and port). If this is a step too far, you may be looking at the route of using VRRP or similar to provide HA capability.